# "rm -rf" equivalent for Windows?

Tags: windows, cmd, wsh

I need a way to recursively delete a folder and its children.

Is there a prebuilt tool for this, or do I need to write one?

`DEL /S` doesn't delete directories.

`DELTREE` was removed from Windows 2000+

Comment: TLDR: use `rmdir /S /Q`

Answer (score 969, accepted):

RMDIR or RD if you are using the classic Command Prompt (cmd.exe):

```
rd /s /q "path"
```

> RMDIR [/S] [/Q] [drive:]path
>
> RD [/S] [/Q] [drive:]path
>
> /S Removes all directories and files in the specified directory in addition to the directory itself. **Used to remove a directory tree.**
>
> /Q Quiet mode, do not ask if ok to remove a directory tree with /S

If you are using PowerShell you can use `Remove-Item` (which is aliased to `del`, `erase`, `rd`, `ri`, `rm` and `rmdir`) and takes a `-Recurse` argument that can be shorted to `-r`

```
rd -r "path"
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that for large numbers of files, rmdir /s /q is typically significantly faster than the equivalent "select dir, shift + delete" operation in explorer.

Comment: How about using flags to match directory names?  If I want to drop all directories under foo\, `rmdir /s /q foo\*` gives an error for syntax incorrect.

Comment: This doesn't delete files, like rm -rf does, and it also returns a non-zero value when the directory doesn't exist, so `rd /s /q foo && echo "yay"` will fail if directory "foo" doesn't exist.

Comment: @Derek, Doskey could help you create aliases for ls=dir: http://devblog.point2.com/2010/05/14/setup-persistent-aliases-macros-in-windows-command-prompt-cmd-exe-using-doskey/

Comment: What if dir. not empty and some files get `Access is denied` and others `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`?

Comment: I just tried this in seven and you need to do /S and /Q (caps)

Comment: Mystified here. I *know* that I tried this command and it did not work if there were files in the directory tree; now I go back and . . . magically it seems to work. Does anyone else experience inconsistent behavior with this?!

Comment: Yes, I experience inconsistent behavior all the time. It says it cannot delete the directory because it is blocked by some process. But there are no processes blocking the directory.

Comment: Use `if exist myfolder ( rmdir /s/q myfolder )` if you don't know whether the folder will exist or not

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in PowerShell? I'm getting "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '/q'."

Comment: @JonGunter for Powershell you use the Remove-Item cmdlet https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item

Comment: Maybe it worked in some older windows. But now it does not work at all.

Comment: `help rmdir` in windows 7 indicates `/S` should be used to remove the whole directory tree and `/Q` should be used for quiet mode.

Comment: `The system cannot find the path specified` :C

Comment: It's also worth pointing out the saying `rd -r` out loud makes you sound like a pirate.

Answer (score 172):

admin:

```
takeown /r /f folder
cacls folder /c /G "ADMINNAME":F /T
rmdir /s folder
```

Works for anything including sys files

EDIT: I actually found the best way which also solves file path too long problem as well:

```
mkdir \empty
robocopy /mir \empty folder
```

Comment: My hero! And one tip: You create your empty folder at C:\empty, then once inside each crazy folder, one can just do `robocopy /mir c:\empty .`

Comment: The `takeown` helped me as I copied folder from Linux system with rsync by mistake and I had no privileges to remove that folder... Not even the robocopy worked. Thanks

Comment: Very nice answer. It works. (all other answers on the page don't). But cacls is deprecated. Is it possible to make a contemporary answer, please? The second variant already works and is not deprecated.

Comment: This doesn't do anything for me. Could someone please explain how it is supposed to work? (robocopy) - It might delete contents of folders, but not folders themselves

Comment: @wbkang when I run `cacls "C:\B" /c /G "ADMINNAME":F /T` I get `No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.`

Comment: @bilal substitute"adminname" with your actual account name.

Comment: @wbkang For me rmdir was not working because few files were having long paths, actually your solution of copying empty folder to folder is a smart solution, thank you

Answer (score 135):

`RMDIR [/S] [/Q] [drive:]path`

`RD [/S] [/Q] [drive:]path`

- **`/S`**      Removes all directories and files in the specified directory in addition to the directory itself.  ***Used to remove a directory tree.***
- `/Q`      Quiet mode, do not ask if ok to remove a directory tree with `/S`

Comment: Simplest, perfect answer to the question. Should be the accepted one.

Comment: @Artif3x: It's the equivalent of `rm -r` not `rm -rf`

Answer (score 28):

Go to the path and trigger this command.

```
rd /s /q "FOLDER_NAME"
```

/s : Removes the specified directory and all subdirectories including any files. Use /s to remove a tree.

/q : Runs rmdir in quiet mode. Deletes directories without confirmation.

/? : Displays help at the command prompt.

Answer (score 22):

You can install cygwin, which has `rm` as well as `ls` etc.

Answer (score 21):

```bsh
rm -r -fo <path>
```

is the closest you can get in Windows PowerShell. It is the abbreviation of

```bsh
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Path <path>
```

[(more details)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61573240/11942268).

Comment: THANK YOU! This suggestion actually worked in Windows Terminal.

Answer (score 18):

For deleting a directory (whether or not it exists) use the following:

```
if exist myfolder ( rmdir /s/q myfolder )
```

Comment: Actually this is the answer. Thanks @Clay

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer is great, but assuming you have Node installed, you can do this much more precisely with the node library "rimraf", which allows globbing patterns. If you use this a lot (I do), just install it globally.

```
yarn global add rimraf
```

then, for instance, a pattern I use constantly:

```
rimraf .\**\node_modules
```

or for a one-liner that let's you dodge the global install, but which takes slightly longer for the the package dynamic download:

```
npx rimraf .\**\node_modules
```

Comment: A solid solution to the problem as it's OS-agnostic.

Answer (score 10):

via Powershell

```
 Remove-Item -Recurse -Force "TestDirectory"
```

via Command Prompt

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35731786/439130

Answer (score 7):

Try this command:

```
del /s foldername
```

Comment: worked for me in combination w/ rmdir /s /q as some files were locked and rmdir would fail on those.  del / foldername nuked the locked files which then allowed rmdir to get rid of root dir.  Nice.

Answer (score 7):

`rmdir /S /Q %DIRNAME%`

Answer (score 4):

First, let’s review what `rm -rf` does:

```
C:\Users\ohnob\things>touch stuff.txt

C:\Users\ohnob\things>rm -rf stuff.txt

C:\Users\ohnob\things>mkdir stuff.txt

C:\Users\ohnob\things>rm -rf stuff.txt

C:\Users\ohnob\things>ls -l
total 0

C:\Users\ohnob\things>rm -rf stuff.txt
```

There are three scenarios where `rm -rf` is commonly used where it is expected to return `0`:

1. The specified path does not exist.
2. The specified path exists and is a directory.
3. The specified path exists and is a file.

I’m going to ignore the whole permissions thing, but nobody uses permissions or tries to deny themselves write access on things in Windows anyways (OK, that’s meant to be a joke…).

First [set `ERRORLEVEL` to 0](https://superuser.com/a/649329/149378) and then delete the path only if it exists, using different commands depending on whether or not it is a directory. `IF EXIST` does not set `ERRORLEVEL` to 0 if the path does not exist, so setting the `ERRORLEVEL` to 0 first is necessary to properly detect success in a way that mimics normal `rm -rf` usage. Guarding the `RD` with `IF EXIST` is necessary because `RD`, unlike `rm -f`, will throw an error if the target does not exist.

The following script snippet assumes that DELPATH is prequoted. (This is safe when you do something like `SET DELPATH=%1`. Try putting `ECHO %1` in a `.cmd` and passing it an argument with spaces in it and see what happens for yourself). After the snippet completes, you can check for failure with `IF ERRORLEVEL 1`.

```
: # Determine whether we need to invoke DEL or RD or do nothing.
SET DELPATH_DELMETHOD=RD
PUSHD %DELPATH% 2>NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (SET DELPATH_DELMETHOD=DEL) ELSE (POPD)
IF NOT EXIST %DELPATH% SET DELPATH_DELMETHOD=NOOP
: # Reset ERRORLEVEL so that the last command which
: # otherwise set it does not cause us to falsely detect
: # failure.
CMD /C EXIT 0
IF %DELPATH_DELMETHOD%==DEL DEL /Q %DELPATH%
IF %DELPATH_DELMETHOD%==RD RD /S /Q %DELPATH%
```

Point is, everything is simpler when the environment just conforms to POSIX. Or if you install a minimal MSYS and just use that.

Answer (score 4):

As a sidenode:

From the linux version with all subdirs (recursive) + force delete

`$   rm -rf ./path`

to PowerShell

`PS> rm -r -fo ./path`

which has the close to same params (just seperated) (-fo is needed, since -f could match different other params)

note:

```
Remove-Item ALIASE
    ri
    rm
    rmdir
    del
    erase
    rd
```

Answer (score 4):

in powershell, rm is alias of `Remove-Item`, so remove a file,

```sh
rm -R -Fo the_file
```

is equivalent to

```sh
Remove-Item -R -Fo the_file
```

if you feel comfortable with gnu `rm` util, you can the `rm` util by [choco](https://chocolatey.org/install) package manager on windows.

install gnu utils in powershell using `choco`:

```sh
choco install GnuWin
```

finally,

```sh
rm.exe -rf the_file
```

Answer (score 3):

rmdir /s dirname

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you need to do...

Create a batch file with the following line

`RMDIR /S %1`

Save your batch file as `Remove.bat` and put it in `C:\windows`

Create the following registry key

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Remove Directory (RMDIR)`

Launch `regedit` and update the default value `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Remove Directory (RMDIR)\default`
with the following value

`"c:\windows\REMOVE.bat" "%1"`

Thats it! Now you can right click any directory and use the RMDIR function

Comment: This is a great start, but the batch file is not needed: cmd.exe /s /c rmdir "%V" is enough

Answer (score 3):

**LATE BUT IMPORTANT ANSWER** to anyone who is having troubles installing [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) packages on windows machine and if you are seeing error saying "`rm -rf...`" command not found.
You can use the [bash cli](https://gitforwindows.org/) to run rm command on windows.

for npm users, you can change the npm's config to `npm config set script-shell "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe"` this way if the npm package you are trying to install has a [post install script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) that uses `rm -rf` command, you will be able to run that `rm` command without needing to change anything in the npm package or disabling the post install scripts config. (For example, `styled-components` uses `rm` command in their post install scripts)

If you want to just use the `rm` command, you can easily use the bash and pass the arguments.

**So yes, you can use the 'rm' command on windows.**

Comment: This solution will add `.npmrc` globally.  
You can undo the solution with `npm config delete script-shell` to get back as default.

If you want the solution to be only local, use:  
`npm config set script-shell "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --userconfig .npmrc`

This will add the `.npmrc` file to your current directory.

Answer (score 3):

In powershell `rm -recurse -force` works quite well.

Comment: `rm` is just (one of the plenty `del, erase, rd, ri, rm, rmdir`) aliases for  `remove-item` wich is already mentioned in answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/63745519/7505395 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/53859156/7505395 and the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/97896/7505395 (which does not explicitly state to use force though - but all the others do)

Comment: Well -Force makes a difference. I found the other answers confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You can install [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) and use *nix commands natively on windows. I install this before I install anything else on a minty fresh copy of windows. :)

Answer (score 2):

Using Powershell 5.1

```
 get-childitem *logs* -path .\ -directory -recurse | remove-item -confirm:$false -recurse -force
```

Replace *logs* with the directory name you want to delete.

**get-childitem** searches for the children directory with the name recursively from current path (.).

**remove-item** deletes the result.

Answer (score 2):

USE AT YOUR OWN RISK. INFORMATION PROVIDED 'AS IS'. NOT TESTED EXTENSIVELY.

Right-click Windows icon (usually bottom left) > click "Windows PowerShell (Admin)" > use this command (with due care, you can easily delete all your files if you're not careful):

```
rd -r -include *.* -force somedir
```

Where `somedir` is the non-empty directory you want to remove.

Note that with external attached disks, or disks with issues, Windows sometimes behaves odd - it does not error in the delete (or any copy attempt), yet the directory is not deleted (or not copied) as instructed. (I found that in this case, at least for me, the command given by @n_y in his answer will produce errors like 'get-childitem : The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.' as a result in PowerShell)

Answer (score 0):

here is what worked for me:

Just try decreasing the length of the path. 
i.e :: Rename all folders that lead to such a file to smallest possible names. Say one letter names. Go on renaming upwards in the folder hierarchy.
By this u effectively reduce the path length.
Now finally try deleting the file straight away.

Answer (score -1):

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\rmdir\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /c rmdir "%V""

Answer (score -3):

There is also deltree if you're on an older version of windows.

You can learn more about it from here:
[SS64: DELTREE - Delete all subfolders and files.](https://ss64.com/nt/deltree.html)