# batch to delete subfolders of all subfolders

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So i'm currently trying to delete a bunch of subfolders that were created by a program, on a recurring basis because it will recreate the subfolders. I know how to schedule the batch file, right now my issue is how to efficiently create the batch file to begin with. To clarify, say i have a directory named `D:\IGSG`. There are 250 folders within `D:\IGSG`, and within each one of those is a folder named `D:\IGSG\F252341\arg`. I want to delete all of the `\arg` folders, from all ~250 F folders I have, without deleting the other files inside the F folders. Right now the only way to do it that I know of would be to have a batch that goes

`cd D:\IGSG\F252341
del /Q arg`

and to repeat those lines for every subfolder, but typing out those folder names for every folder in there would be tedious, especially considering new ones are created from time to time. So i'm looking for a way with a batch to delete the subfolder of a subfolder, without deleting other files, if that makes sense.

Comment: There is similar question that was answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748786/delete-files-or-folder-recursively-on-windows-cmd

Answer (score 1):

This PowerShell script will recurse through the subdirectory structure and delete all files and subdirectories inside `arg` directories. Be sure to change the location of the IGSG directory to yours. When you are satisfied that the correct files will be deleted, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Remove-Item` cmdlet.

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse -Path 'C:\src\t\delsubs\IGSG\F*' -Filter 'arg' |
    Remove-Item -Path {(Join-Path -Path $_.FullName -ChildPath '*')} -Recurse -Force -WhatIf
```

If you need to run it from a cmd.exe shell, put the code above into a file named 'dodel.ps1' and run using:

```
powershell -NoProfile -File .\dodel.ps1
```

Comment: As Remove-Item accepts piped input, the ForEach can be avoided, you just have to put the -Path paramter in a {script block}. One of the rare cases where batch/cmd line can compete

Comment: @LotPings - I appreciate your suggestion. I have tried several things, but not gotten it yet. How are you suggesting the `Remove-Item` line be written?

Comment: `Remove-Item -Path {(Join-Path -Path $_.FullName -ChildPath '*')} -Recurse -Force -WhatIf` and remove the `ForEach-Object {}` it worked when I tried mine batch vs your ps1.

Comment: @LotPings - Great suggestion. It is going in now.

Answer (score 1):

On the cmd line `for /d /r X:\path` in combination with a wildcard will enumerate all folders names `arg` the appended `.?` meets this requirement:

```
for /d /r D:\IGSG %A in (arg.?) do @echo rd /s /q "%A"
```

if the output looks right remove the echo.

In a batch file double the %-signs -> %%A

```
@Echo off
for /d /r D:\IGSG %%A in (arg.?) do echo rd /s /q "%%A"
```

One of the rare cases where batch/cmd line can compete with PowerShell.