# How to delete Node_modules folder in command line on Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line

So, I should delete all node_modules in my project(I want that the node_modules folder become completely empty). Just removing folder manually does not suit me.

I read that I can delete it with `rm -rf node_modules/` BUT it does not work on WINDOWS.

How to delete it?

Comment: DEL /F /Q /A node_modules/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete files/subfolders in a specific directory at the command prompt in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965787/how-to-delete-files-subfolders-in-a-specific-directory-at-the-command-prompt-in)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete files or folder recursively on Windows CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748786/delete-files-or-folder-recursively-on-windows-cmd)

Answer (score 7):

Deleting node_modules is as simple as writing the node_modules without a slash:

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

`rm -rf node_modules` shouldn't have a slash at the end `/`, and this worked for me even on Widows.

Comment: This simple command works in Git Bash also `rm -rf node_modules`.

Comment: The `-rf` option tells it to also recursively delete non-empty directories and subdirectories, forcefully

Comment: That should be peculiar to you, because, all the time, I had the course to use `-rf` prefix, it has never deleted any other file, say the specific file or folder it is prefixed with. Forcefully, yeah, but using just `rm` gives you a different error message.

Answer (score 6):

Installing globally rimraf will do the job.

`npm install -g rimraf`

From the docs:

> If installed with `npm install rimraf -g` it can be used as a global
>   command rimraf  [ ...] which is useful for cross platform
>   support.

So with installing this package, you can remove directories on all platforms(windows, linux).

All left to do is `rimraf node_modules`

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a number of developers facing issues with disk space being consumed heavily by 'node_modules' folders, especially when working with JavaScript projects. To assist with this, I have developed a Python script that quickly and efficiently deletes all 'node_modules' folders in a directory and its immediate subdirectories.

The script uses multi-threading to enhance the speed of the deletion process.

```py
import os
import shutil
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def delete_node_modules_path(node_modules_path):
    try:
        shutil.rmtree(node_modules_path)
        print(f"Successfully deleted the folder: {node_modules_path}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Could not delete the folder {node_modules_path} due to the following error: {e}")

def delete_node_modules(base_path):
    # Verify if the provided path exists
    if not os.path.exists(base_path):
        print(f"The specified path does not exist: {base_path}")
        return

    # Get a list of all immediate subdirectories
    subdirs = [os.path.join(base_path, d) for d in os.listdir(base_path) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(base_path, d))]
    
    # Traverse only one level down the directory structure and delete 'node_modules' folders
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for subdir in subdirs:
            node_modules_path = os.path.join(subdir, 'node_modules')
            if os.path.exists(node_modules_path):
                print(f"Processing: {subdir}")
                executor.submit(delete_node_modules_path, node_modules_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    base_path = os.getcwd()
    print(f"The current base path is: {base_path}")
    delete_node_modules(base_path)
```