# Using Makefile, how can I delete object files in a sub-directory?

Tags: makefile

I am new to using makefile in Windows, and I've been trying hard to learn this.
When I try to delete object files using clean option, it keeps making errors.
There's Makefile and 3 sub-directories and each sub-directory has a .cpp file. I want to delete .o files in each sub-directory, but when I write down my code like
clean:
        delete *.o
it doesn't work.
How can I delete object files in sub-directories?

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748786/delete-files-or-folder-recursively-on-windows-cmd answer?

Comment: How woud you delete these files from the command line? In general, you can't do something with Make until you know how to do it *without* Make.