# How do I delete subfolders with the same name under multiple directories in Windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a folder tree similar to this:

```
main_folder\folder1\Debug\(file1.a1, file2.a2, file3.a3 ...)  
main_folder\folder2\Debug\(file1.a1, file2.a2, file3.a3 ...)  
main_folder\folder3\Debug\(file1.a1, file2.a2, file3.a3 ...)
```

folder1, 2, 3 contain many other files and folders besides Debug. Debug subfolder is not empty in any of the folders. I want to delete the Debug subfolder (and everything in it) from all folders 1, 2, 3. How do I delete the Debug subfolder in all these folders using a bat script?

Comment: For usage in a command prompt window: `for /F "delims=" %I in ('dir "C:\path\main_folder\debug" /AD-L /B /S 2^>nul') do if exist "%I\" rd /Q /S "%I"` which removes all directories quietly and with all subdirectories and files with name `debug` found in `C:\path\main_folder` or any subdirectory of that directory and its entire directory tree. Replace all three occurrences of `%I` by `%%I` for usage of this command line in a batch file. `if exist "%I\"` can be omitted on no directory with name `debug` contains ever in its directory tree another directory with name `debug`.

Comment: @Mofi this worked. If you can post it as an answer I will accept.

Comment: Please read my answer on [Delete files or folder recursively on Windows CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71547603/3074564) if you are interested in an explanation how exactly this command line works. I don't want to explain the command line a second time. Well, there is one difference: `if exist "%I\"` is used to avoid the attempt to delete a `debug` folder being a subfolder of a `debug` folder which was already deleted before. The referenced answer contains the command line with `2>nul` to simply suppress any error message output like on folder to delete not existing anymore.

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED
It loop thropugh main_folder, read names of its subdirs than delete Debug subfolder of each main_folder subfolder, including its content.

`for /f "tokens=3 delims=\" %%a in ('dir /b /s /a:d "main_folder"') do rd /S main_folder\%%a\Debug`