# Windows equivalent of rm -rf [Don't want to delete parent directory]

Tags: windows, batch-file, mkdir, rmdir

I am doing the same as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/97896/1175065b) i.e. In my batch file, I am using `rmdir E:\docs\music /S /Q` to delete all the content including sub directories too but it is removing parent directory `music` also which I don't want.
Do I need to run `mkdir` everytime?

Comment: Have you tried using wildcards?

Comment: `rmdir E:\docs\music\* /S /Q`  is showing `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single line solution uses `for` to produce a list of the inner directories :

```
for /f %i in ('dir /ad /b music') do @rmdir /s /q music\%i
```

You must escape the `%` if you put that line in a batch file, like this :

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /ad /b music') do @rmdir /s /q music\%%i
```

Answer (score 3):

If you `cd` into `E:\docs\music` then execute `rmdir E:\docs\music /S /Q` everything will be deleted under `music` but not the `music` directory itself.

Comment: When I tried it, `music` was also gone.