# How to recursively delete from Visual Studios file system? is it even possible?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

When making a installer (using Visual Studio Installer) I am getting rather tired of having to manually delete hundreds of individual files every time my application changes.

It boggles my mind that Visual Studio doesn't seem to let you do a recursive delete - instead insisting that every file from every subfolder is deleted in turn. For my project this means I either;

a) Have to spend hours deleting files from the filesystem view.

b) Recreate the installer project each time.

Is there something I am doing wrong? Is there a workaround people use for this stuff?
Sorry if this has been posted before, cant seem to find the right keywords if it has - I certainly find it hard to believe no one else ever needs to remove folders from the filesystem.

What is the accepted best method for removing folders with lots of files?

[image]

*edit*

To be clear; This isn't a real file system. I can deleted real files of my hard disc without problems. This is Visual Studios impression of a file system. Removing the real files does not remove reference to them, and instead will just produce more errors telling me the files are missing.

Answer (score -1):

On a Linux I'd say

```
rm -rf /path/to/dir/or/file
```

Since you're on Windows I browsed the web for an equivalent statement and found this:

> RMDIR or RD:
>   `rd /s /q`

As described by *Duncan Smart* right here on SO: [RM -rf equivalent for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97875/rm-rf-equivalent-for-windows)

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. I was not talking about the real filesystem, but rather the virtual filesystem in visual studio. Thats not a real directory in the screenshot, but rather the "target file structure" that will result from the install of the app.
If I removed the (real) source files that virtual file structure would remain, only with red underlines telling me that are all missing files.

Comment: Do you have methods to remove such a virtual file and/or change directory? If so it's easy to recursively define it.