# Symfony2 - The class 'X' was not found in the chain configured namespaces

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, mapping

I've been searching forever to solve my problem. But I can't find any solution.

I always get this error message when I try to open the homepage:

**Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException' with message 'The class 'Test\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User' was not found in the chain configured namespaces ' in...**

The weird thing is that I only get it when I have following URL:

http://localhost/

But when I run it on this URL I don't get any error and my page is being displayed correctly:

http://localhost/app_dev.php

My Configuration looks like this (config.yml):

```
# Doctrine Configuration
dbal:
  default_connection: default
  connections:
    default:
      driver:   "%database_driver%"
      host:     "%database_host%"
      port:     "%database_port%"
      dbname:   "%database_name%"
      user:     "%database_user%"
      password: "%database_password%"
      charset:  UTF8
    test:
      driver:   "%database_driver2%"
      host:     "%database_host2%"
      port:     "%database_port2%"
      dbname:   "%database_name2%"
      user:     "%database_user2%"
      password: "%database_password2%"
      charset:  UTF8
orm:
  default_entity_manager: default
  entity_managers:
    default:
      connection: default
      mappings:
        TestUserBundle:
          type: annotation
```

And I call Doctrine in my custom service like this:

```
public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
{
    $repositiory = $em->getRepository('Test\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User');
    $this->user = $repositiory->find($_SERVER['AUTH_USER']);
}
```

My Symfony Application is running on an IIS Webserver.

Do you guys know where I made a mistake?

Comment: did you do a `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod` ?

Comment: I tried to do it but I get an error that I can't rename the cache directory "prod"

Comment: Then go to the directory `app/cache/prod` and delete everything within this directory.

Comment: You need to temporarily stop any PHP processes that might be using the `prod` directory (i.e. if you've ran `console server:run`) and try again. If that doesn't do it, try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97875/rm-rf-equivalent-for-windows

Comment: Thanks I totally forgot about the processes. It worked now thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mapping name is `TestUserBundle` but the path is `Test\Bundle\User\Bundle`, shouldn't it be named `TestBundleUserBundle` instead? Also, usually the `mappings` and `auto_generate_proxy_classes` are set to `true` in dev mode which might explain why it's working there and not in prod.

You might want to checkout the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#custom-mapping-entities-in-a-bundle) (Symfony 2.7) which shows how exactly you should be configuring the mappings depending on your case.

## Custom Mapping Entities in a Bundle

```
doctrine:
    # ...
    orm:
        # ...
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            # ...
            AppBundle:
                type: xml
                dir: SomeResources/config/doctrine
```

## Mapping Entities Outside of a Bundle

```
doctrine:
    # ...
    orm:
        # ...
        mappings:
            # ...
            SomeEntityNamespace:
                type: annotation
                dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/Entity"
                is_bundle: false
                prefix: App\Entity
                alias: App
```

Last, but not least, always clear your cache directory after applying changes to the `config.yml` or files in the `app/config/` directory.

As mentioned in the comments:
You need to temporarily stop any PHP processes that might be using the prod directory (i.e. if you've ran console server:run) and try again. If that doesn't do it, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97875/rm-rf-equivalent-for-windows)

Comment: Since my Entity is in the Entity directory and I use annotations I could use just the auto_mapping because my configuration is not somewhere else right?

Comment: Yes, it should be working fine that way. I have my entities in `App/MyBundle/Entity/EntityName` and in the config I have `auto_mapping: true` - works like a charm. You still need to clear the cache after applying the change, though.

Comment: Yes I left it like this now and I cleared the cached now (after closing all php processes) It works like a charm. Could you add to your answer that you have to close all processes for clearing the cache of the production? Then I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my mistake was that I forgot to add distant bundles/bundles in "vendor" inside my AppKernel file.

They weren't registered in the "registerBundles" function.