# Convert package.json scripts for windows platform

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to build from [isomorphic-flux-boilerplate](https://github.com/iam4x/isomorphic-flux-boilerplate)

This build script will not work for windows:

```
"build": "rm -rf dist && babel-node ./node_modules/.bin/webpack --stats --config  ./webpack/prod.config.js",
```

Does anyone know it's windows counterpart?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error details.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of `rm -rf` command. You can try replacing it with the answer from this question [RM -rf equivalent for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97875/rm-rf-equivalent-for-windows)

Comment: Even if I remove the clean (ie. rm -rf) the script still does not work.

Comment: What are the error messages shown? Do you have babel installed globally?

Comment: The dev runs finid: "dev": "babel-node ./webpack/dev-server.js",