# Is it possible to not generate package-lock.json with npm 5?

Tags: npm

I've updated `npm` to it's latest version recently to get the performance upgrade. But since my company hasn't updated globally, I don't want the usage of package-lock.json.

I could simply ignore it in git workflow by adding `package-lock.json` to my `.git/info/exclude`. But it would still be used by npm when installing or updating dependencies.

So how can I tell npm **not** to use it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Deactivate `package-lock.json` usage globally

To disable it globally, you'll have to set your `package-lock` to `false` in your `~/.npmrc`. You can do it by using:

```
npm config set package-lock false
```

This will allow you to use npm@5 performance without bothering with package-lock.json. Though package-lock.json has many benefits [according to npm doc](/docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json), and you may consider using it.

## Deactivate `package-lock.json` usage per command

According to [npm-cli doc](//docs.npmjs.com/cli/install), you can use `--no-package-lock` options for the `install` command:

```
npm install --no-package-lock any-lib
```

And according to [this question](/q/45040079/6320039), existing `package-lock.json` will not be taken care of.

Answer (score 12):

To disable `package-lock.json` in a project you can add
`.npmrc` file and content of this file will be

```
package-lock=false
```

if you try to install with `npm` the file will not generate.

Comment: When you do this, if you explicitly generate a package-lock.json ie - `npm i --package-lock-only` will subsequent npm installs respect that package-lock.json or skip it entirely?