# npm run build throws code ELIFECYCLE after installing all dependencies for lodash

Tags: javascript, npm, lodash

I have been trying to run the lodash library on my system.Here is the link to the library .[link to lodash github](https://github.com/lodash/lodash)

. I forked the repo and then cloned it on my system .I ran npm install ad installed all the dependencies in the package.json by running npm install and it worked fine .After that i tried npm run build as shown on github page and I am getting this error .

```
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/satya/lodash/lib/main/build-dist.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! lodash@4.17.4 build:main: `node lib/main/build-dist.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the lodash@4.17.4 build:main script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

How do I resolve the above so that I can introduce console logs and start reading .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle)

Comment: You may already have it running in another git bash window.

Comment: No .I have only command line running on my system now

Comment: I'm a little confused why you're asking about that here, instead of the place you literally linked us to as being the authoritative source. They have an issue tracker, did you file this on https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues to ask them whether this is a known issue and where the documentation is that explains how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

[lodash's master branch is simply broken](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/3140). From [CONTRIBUTING.md](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md):

> Notice
>
> Pardon the mess. The master branch is in flux while we
> work on Lodash v5. This means things like npm scripts, which we
> encourage using for contributions, may not be working. Thank you for
> your patience.

Simply use the latest development branch, which is [4.17](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/tree/4.17) as of now.

On another note, to understand which branches are under active development on any project on GitHub, go to `https://github.com/<user or organization name>/<project name>/branches/active`.