# npm ERR! awesome-typescript-loader@4.0.0-0 postinstall

Tags: angular, npm

I get below lines of error when i am trying to do npm install for my project.

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! awesome-typescript-loader@4.0.0-0 postinstall: `node node_modules/husky/bin/install.js || true`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the awesome-typescript-loader@4.0.0-0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Any help would be aprecciated.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle

Comment: Check this : https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader/issues/543