# react-native node dependency install broke project

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, npm-install, expo

I am trying to develop my first android app using [react-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native) and [expo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo) for testing, on windows 8.1.

Working from a tutorial I had a working project using [react-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native)  components but everything broke when I installed a dependency with

```
`npm install --save react-navigation`:
```

`npm-start` returned

> Error: React native is not installed. Please run 'npm install' in your project directory.

So I ran `npm-install` again as suggested.
This led to `npm-start` asking me if I want to install [expo-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-cli) globally, and whether I answer yes or no I get the following error:

```
Installing the package [expo-cli][1]...
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn npm ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:232:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:407:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:238:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:407:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! empty-project-template@ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the empty-project-template@ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-09-25T21_27_21_053Z-debug.log
```

The log mentioned in this message is as follows:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.11.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle empty-project-template@~prestart: empty-project-template@
6 info lifecycle empty-project-template@~start: empty-project-template@
7 verbose lifecycle empty-project-template@~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle empty-project-template@~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\androidProjects\MoviesAndMe\node_modules\.bin;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\libnvvp;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1\libnvvp;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Android;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\me\Documents\Latex\miktex\bin\;C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\hyper\app-2.0.0\resources\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin;C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle empty-project-template@~start: CWD: D:\androidProjects\MoviesAndMe
10 silly lifecycle empty-project-template@~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'expo start' ]
11 silly lifecycle empty-project-template@~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle empty-project-template@~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: empty-project-template@ start: `expo start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
14 verbose pkgid empty-project-template@
15 verbose cwd D:\androidProjects\MoviesAndMe
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.3.9600
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v10.11.0
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error empty-project-template@ start: `expo start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the empty-project-template@ start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I searched on StackOverflow and followed the advice to deal with `ELIFECYCLE` errors found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49505612/8650928). runnning `npm cache clean` then deleting the `node_modules` directory and `package-lock.json` buit the error is the same.
I even tried doing these steps as well as removing the `react-navigation` from my dependencies in my `package.json` file and in my code before running `npm-install` again, but it didn't change anything.

It is interesting to note that when running `expo start` on it's own it manages to launch the bundler and the devtools in the browser just not with the right ip address.

I also don't know if this is important but when running `npm-install` I get 2 vulnerabilities, when I run `npm-audit` it indicates that the is a low 'Prototype Pollution' vulnerability in the lodash package and a High 'Denial of Service' vulnerability in the ws package. But nothing changes even after running `npm audit fix`

Anyway I hope you can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem.

If you run:

```
npm i expo-cli
```

and then

```
npm start
```

It will work

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot! Do you know what the problem was then?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, angular-cli was not installed so I ran the command as -

```
npm install -g angular-cli
```