# appuim installation with node js

Tags: node.js, appium

how to solve this problem?

```
verbose node v10.14.2

verbose npm  v6.4.1

error code ELIFECYCLE

error errno 1

error appium-chromedriver@4.10.0 install: `node install-npm.js`

error Exit status 1

error Failed at the appium-chromedriver@4.10.0 install script.

error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Read this doc: http://appium.io/docs/en/about-appium/getting-started/#installation-via-npm

Comment: @dear binayak I did all the steps in this document, but I repeatedly see this error.

Comment: Can you please mention how did you get the error? What were you trying to do? Are you trying to install something?

Comment: Also can you tell which command did you execute to install appium?

Comment: @ suban i try to install appium with "npm install -g appium" in powershell

Comment: Try using node 8+ instead of 10+. It works for me and hopefully will work for you as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle)

Comment: The last resort which I did worked. Formatted the entire mac machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would highly recommend using a [node version manager](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) for Node/npm installation.

Appium installation works perfectly with node version **10.1.0**:

`nvm install 10.1.0
//in new shell
nvm use node
npm install -g appium`

Update: I think you are facing [a similar issue](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/9100), caused by **Windows firewall** or **some proxy**.

What you need to do is set the `--chromedriver_cdnurl` flag during npm install to the server which is accessible within your firewall:

`npm install -g appium --chromedriver_cdnurl=http://localhost:1234`

Maybe even better to setup npm proxy following [instructions](https://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy/)

Comment: I'm installed nodejs v10.1.0 but i see again this error...
C:\Windows\System32>node -v
v10.1.0

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! appium-chromedriver@4.10.1 install: `node install-npm.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the appium-chromedriver@4.10.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.

Answer (score 1):

This worked: sudo npm install -g appium --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root

Comment: You should never install appium via sudo as you may face issues with service programmatic start.