# How to fix Error occurred when executing command 'npm run server' and 'npm run client' concurrently in 'npm run dev' command in ReactJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am working with MERN web application and trying to running both Client and Server at the same time using 'npm run dev' command and getting below error.

mernshoppinglist@1.0.0 dev F:\React\MernShoppingList
concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client"

```
[0] Error occurred when executing command: npm run server
[0] Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
[0]     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:229:19)
[0]     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:406:16)
[0]     at process._tickCallback 
(internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
[0]     at Function.Module.runMain 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:11)
[0]     at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:238:19)
[0]     at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:572:3)
[1] Error occurred when executing command: npm run client
[1] Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
[1]     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:229:19)
[1]     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:406:16)
[1]     at process._tickCallback 
(internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
[1]     at Function.Module.runMain 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:11)
[1]     at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:238:19)
[1]     at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:572:3)
[1] npm run client exited with code -4058
[0] npm run server exited with code -4058

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mernshoppinglist@1.0.0 dev: `concurrently "npm run 
server" "npm run client"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mernshoppinglist@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Tmp\nodejs\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01- 
24T04_08_31_288Z-debug.log
```

debug.log file

0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'dev' ]
2 info using npm@6.1.0
3 info using node@v10.4.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle mernshoppinglist@1.0.0~predev: mernshoppinglist@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle mernshoppinglist@1.0.0~dev: mernshoppinglist@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle mernshoppinglist@1.0.0~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle mernshoppinglist@1.0.0~dev: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;F:\React\MernShoppingList\node_modules.bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.3\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Users\CHAMATH PC\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin
9 verbose lifecycle mernshoppinglist@1.0.0~dev: CWD: F:\React\MernShoppingList
10 silly lifecycle mernshoppinglist@1.0.0~dev: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client"' ]
11 silly lifecycle mernshoppinglist@1.0.0~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle mernshoppinglist@1.0.0~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: mernshoppinglist@1.0.0 dev: `concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client"`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:304:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:5)
14 verbose pkgid mernshoppinglist@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd F:\React\MernShoppingList
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v10.4.0
19 verbose npm  v6.1.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error mernshoppinglist@1.0.0 dev: `concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client"`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the mernshoppinglist@1.0.0 dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: Welcome to SO, check content of file:`C:\Tmp\nodejs\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-24T04_08_31_288Z-debug.log` and add that too in question

Comment: @dkb I added debug.log in my question.Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: are you running `npm start` from powershell? if not please do that

Comment: check solutions posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42308879/2987755

Comment: @dkb any of the above solutions didn't work for me but when i run my client application and server application separately it worked properly.  Only the error occur when run both client and server application using one command  'npm run dev'.