# unable to compile assets in production with npm run production

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, webpack, laravel-mix

`npm run production` doesn't run successfully. I have tried to remove the node_modules folder and run `npm install` but nothing still. 
I have also tried to uninstall and install npm from the system but I still am having the same issue.

But watch is running fine but not production.

production script does:

```
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
```

I am using npm version 6.7.0 and nodejs version 8.11.4
The script consoles the following error in the npm error log:

`0 info it worked if it ends with ok
    1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'prod' ]
    2 info using npm@6.7.0
    3 info using node@v8.11.4
    4 verbose run-script [ 'preprod', 'prod', 'postprod' ]
    5 info lifecycle @~preprod: @
    6 info lifecycle @~prod: @
    7 verbose lifecycle @~prod: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
    8 verbose lifecycle @~prod: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/var/www/html/****/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
    9 verbose lifecycle @~prod: CWD: /var/www/html/****
    10 silly lifecycle @~prod: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run production' ]
    11 silly lifecycle @~prod: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
    12 info lifecycle @~prod: Failed to exec prod script
    13 verbose stack Error: @ prod: npm run production
    13 verbose stack Exit status 1
    13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
    13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
    13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
    13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
    14 verbose pkgid @
    15 verbose cwd /var/www/html/****
    16 verbose Linux 4.18.0-11-generic
    17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "prod"
    18 verbose node v8.11.4
    19 verbose npm  v6.7.0
    20 error code ELIFECYCLE
    21 error errno 1
    22 error @ prod: npm run production
    22 error Exit status 1
    23 error Failed at the @ prod script.
    23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]`

Comment: Can you show what the script 'production' does?

Comment: added it in the edit above

Comment: Check if this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle

Comment: Thanks @MihirBhende, I just got rid of the `package-lock.json` and re-run `npm run production` and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue because I used to put `MIX_SENTRY_DSN_PUBLIC` in webpack like this (NOT WORKING):

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', process.env.MIX_SENTRY_DSN_PUBLIC/'public/js')
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', process.env.MIX_SENTRY_DSN_PUBLIC/'public/css');
```

instead of:

```
 mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```