# Errors while running "npm run lint"

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-redux, eslint

When I'm trying to run eslint on my project - I'm getting some npm errors.

Eslint is configured but it says unable to find the configuration file.

Using ESLint version - 4.19.1

This is the error log -

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'lint' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.15.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prelint', 'lint', 'postlint' ]
5 info lifecycle react-redux-boilerplate@1.0.0~prelint: react-redux-boilerplate@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle react-redux-boilerplate@1.0.0~lint: react-redux-boilerplate@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle react-redux-boilerplate@1.0.0~lint: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle react-redux-boilerplate@1.0.0~lint: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/sriram/Documents/Wavelabs/PROJECTS_FOLDER/evergent-react/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
9 verbose lifecycle react-redux-boilerplate@1.0.0~lint: CWD: /Users/sriram/Documents/Wavelabs/PROJECTS_FOLDER/evergent-react
10 silly lifecycle react-redux-boilerplate@1.0.0~lint: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run lint:js' ]
11 silly lifecycle react-redux-boilerplate@1.0.0~lint: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle react-redux-boilerplate@1.0.0~lint: Failed to exec lint script
13 verbose stack Error: react-redux-boilerplate@1.0.0 lint: `npm run lint:js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
14 verbose pkgid react-redux-boilerplate@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/sriram/Documents/Wavelabs/PROJECTS_FOLDER/evergent-react
16 verbose Darwin 18.2.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "lint"
18 verbose node v10.15.0
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error react-redux-boilerplate@1.0.0 lint: `npm run lint:js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the react-redux-boilerplate@1.0.0 lint script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I've tried the solutions given in this old post -

[npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle)

But I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: Post your script