# All npm scripts fail, even though scripts themselves can run

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

Any NPM module I try to install fails on the npm-scripts, like postinstall for example.
If I run it as `npm run postinstall` it also fails.
It I run the script postinstall calls directly (IE `node whatever.js`) it works no problem. Unfortunately this has lead me to be unable to install any module that uses npm-scripts.

I created a super simple package to show the problem.

```
{
  "name": "gahhh",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node script.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

`script.js` contains:

```
'use strict';

console.log('Hello?');
```

Output from running:

```
C:\Workspace\testing>npm run postinstall

> gahhh@1.0.0 postinstall C:\Workspace\testing
> node script.js

npm ERR! file bash
npm ERR! path bash
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn bash
npm ERR! gahhh@1.0.0 postinstall: `node script.js`
npm ERR! spawn bash ENOENT
```

Verbose error output:

```
C:\Workspace\testing>npm run postinstall --verbose
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   'run',
npm verb cli   'postinstall',
npm verb cli   '--verbose' ]
npm info using npm@6.8.0
npm info using node@v10.15.1
npm verb run-script [ 'postinstall' ]
npm info lifecycle gahhh@1.0.0~postinstall: gahhh@1.0.0

> gahhh@1.0.0 postinstall C:\Workspace\testing
> node script.js

npm verb lifecycle gahhh@1.0.0~postinstall: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
npm verb lifecycle gahhh@1.0.0~postinstall: PATH: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Workspace\testing\node_modules\.bin;c:\program files\graphicsmagick-1.3.31-q16;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\WebEx\Productivity Tools;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin;C:\Program Files\maven\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\USERNAME\.windows-build-tools\python27\;C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sennheiser\SoftphoneSDK\;C:\Program Files (x86)\WebEx\Productivity Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\WebEx\PTools020000000;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\maven\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm verb lifecycle gahhh@1.0.0~postinstall: CWD: C:\Workspace\testing
npm info lifecycle gahhh@1.0.0~postinstall: Failed to exec postinstall script
npm info lifecycle gahhh@1.0.0~postinstall: Failed to exec postinstall script
npm verb stack Error: gahhh@1.0.0 postinstall: `node script.js`
npm verb stack spawn bash ENOENT
npm verb stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
npm verb stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
npm verb stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
npm verb pkgid gahhh@1.0.0
npm verb cwd C:\Workspace\testing
npm verb Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm verb argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "postinstall" "--verbose"
npm verb node v10.15.1
npm verb npm  v6.8.0
npm ERR! file bash
npm ERR! path bash
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn bash
npm ERR! gahhh@1.0.0 postinstall: `node script.js`
npm ERR! spawn bash ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the gahhh@1.0.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm verb exit [ 1, true ]
npm timing npm Completed in 230ms

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-16T17_36_05_033Z-debug.log
```

I get the expected output if I run `node script.js`, so at this point I'm banging my head against my desk. I've run out of ideas.

node version: `v10.15.1`
npm version: `6.8.0`

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49505612/8434189

Comment: @MaStErNeWbIe Hi, I tried that previously, and just tried it again now. Didn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK after a very long time of searching apparently some how `shell=bash` got into my `.npmrc` file. Since I am using Windows, `bash` isn't going to work for me. Removing this line altogether fixed the issue.

Thought I would share this in case anyone else runs into this issue.

Comment: Yes, the same happened to me, and the thing is this is not solved reinstalling npm, those files survive when you uninstall npm, for more info check this https://github.com/npm/cli

Comment: I've been searching for days for that and not a single solution came up for this thing.!
Thank you!