# Error in running nuxt project: "'nuxt' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

When I tried to run `npm run dev` in my nuxt project, my console returned this message:

```
'nuxt' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! andromeda@1.0.0 dev: `nuxt`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the andromeda@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: What version of node, npm and nuxt do you have?

Comment: Have you run `npm install`?

Comment: I tried run npm install alrady.
nuxt@2.6.1
node v10.15.3
npm 6.4.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I solved this problem.
I was looking in stackoverflow for similar problems and apparently the problem was the npm cache.
I will let a link bellow with the solution and a quick sample of what i did.

Link to the answer:
[npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle)

> Step 1: `npm cache clean --force`
>
> Step 2: Delete node_modules by $ `rm -rf node_modules` folder or delete
>   it manually by going into the directory and right-click > delete.
>   Delete `package-lock.json` file too.
>
> Step 3: `npm install`
>
> To start again,  `npm start`

Thanks everyone who take time to help, really appreciate.

Comment: This answer also solved the similar problem I had with `nuxt-ts`. Thank you !

Answer (score 16):

Make sure `nuxt` is installed in your Nuxt project:

```
$ cd /path/to/nuxt-project
$ npm list nuxt
nuxt-project@1.0.0 /path/to/nuxt-project
└── nuxt@2.6.3
```

Here */path/to/nuxt-project* contains your *package.json* and *node-modules*.

If it isn't installed, [add `nuxt` to your project](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/installation/#installing-code-nuxt-code-) by doing:

```
$ npm install --save nuxt
```

Or put it in your project's *package.json* then do `npm install`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "nuxt": "^2.0.0"
  },
```

---

**UPDATE**:
If you are still getting "nuxt not recognized" problems, try to use explicit path to `nuxt` from your *node_modules* directory.

Given this directory (after doing `npm install --save nuxt`):

```
nuxt-project
|- node_modules
   |- .bin
      |- nuxt
|- package.json
```

Update the `dev` command in *package.json* with:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "node_modules/.bin/nuxt"
},
```

Comment: It still has the same error.
My dependencies:
  "dependencies": {
    "nuxt": "^2.4.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.11",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.3.6"
  },

Comment: @Marquezz Just to be sure, you are running `npm install` and `npm run dev` under the project directory? What do you get when you do `npm list nuxt`?

Comment: I am sure that i'm on the right directory.and when i run npm list nuxt i get this:
`-- nuxt@2.6.1
I search on google and i found some people having problems with nuxt + windows 10

Comment: @Marquezz Oh OK. I updated my answer. Try to change the `dev` command to use the explicit node_modules path for `nuxt`.

Comment: I followed these steps and this error went away for me. But, I had to use `yarn install` after this to link the dependencies properly and do `npm run dev`

Answer (score 10):

Sometimes this blows up because you're not exporting `node_modules/.bin` directory.

Place or append the following line in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`:

`export PATH=node_modules/.bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 3):

Have the same problem recently.

Solution for me was change the path of scripts section in *package.json* from this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
```

to that:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node_modules/.bin/nuxt",
    "build": "node_modules/.bin/nuxt build",
    "start": "node_modules/.bin/nuxt start",
     "generate": "node_modules/.bin/nuxt generate"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1: rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
- Step 2: npm cache clean --force
- Step 3: npm install ( you may need to add --legacy-peer-deps or --force flag, if npm install is not working )
- To start again, npm start
- To make build, npm run build (ssr ) or generate ( csr )

Answer (score 0):

Migrating from `Nuxt 2` to `Nuxt 3`?

Change your `scripts` in `package.json` to not refer to `nuxt-ts` anymore, but just to `nuxt` instead. Example: `"dev": "nuxt-ts",` -> `"dev": "nuxt dev",`, `"generate": "nuxt-ts generate",` -> `"generate": "nuxt generate",`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

after installing the project. You need to install packages in package.json

Answer (score -3):

It simply means nuxt is not installed.

Try running `npm install nuxt`

Answer (score -4):

Install globally cross-env:
`npm install -g cross-env`

Then just update package.json scripts to start with "cross-env ...."

example:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env nuxt",
    "build": "cross-env nuxt build",
    "start": "cross-env nuxt start",
    "generate": "cross-env nuxt generate",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore ."
},
```

This works on my Windows 10.

Comment: what does cross-env have to do with nuxt being undefined?