# Permission denied on "npm start" for a react project deployed to server

Tags: reactjs, npm, deployment

I have a react project which works fine on my desktop running "npm start" but after copying the directory to the server (server os is CentOS), when running "npm start" I get this error:

[image]

Is there something I need to configure for it to run on the server?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle)

Comment: Thanks Mercurius, it seemed to me like a different problem at first, but I will try to follow the suggested solutions there and report back thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `node_modules` folder, and run `npm install` again.