# Cannot install angular on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: angular, installation, command-line-interface

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 130
npm ERR! @angular/cli@8.1.0 postinstall: `node ./bin/postinstall/script.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 130
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @angular/cli@8.1.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I receive this error when i am downloading angular. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried with sudo command ?

Comment: I have this error when i run the installation with sudo

Comment: Try this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle/49505612#49505612

Comment: Which version of node are you using?

Comment: the version is 10.16.0