# Permission denied while trying to install opencv4nodejs in Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, opencv, npm, appium, appium-android

I was trying to install `opencv4nodejs` in `Ubuntu-20.04` using the following command and my node version is `v12.19.0`

```
sudo npm i -g opencv4nodejs
```

But getting those errors

```
info install installing opencv version 3.4.6 into directory: /usr/lib/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/node_modules/opencv-build/opencv
ERR! Error: Command failed: mkdir -p opencv
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘opencv’: Permission denied
 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! opencv-build@0.1.9 install: `node ./install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the opencv-build@0.1.9 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-10-28T06_33_21_090Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Running NPM install with sudo might be causing a permissions problem. You could try completely removing the node_modules directory and re-running NPM install it without sudo.
2. Also make sure you have permission to write to the directory you're installing in?
3. If it still doesn't work please follow this:

   ```
   sudo npm install -g opencv4nodejs --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
   ```

Comment: In my case, due to corporate PC, I must use sudo to use npm install. But the 3rd option worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is complete guide to install opencv4nodejs to Linux OS or Raspberry pi (Raspberry Pi OS )

configuration

```
   01- sudo raspi-config  expand file system  // this is for raspberry pi 
   After Reboot (sudo reboot now)
   02- df -h (To check expand file system)
   03- sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
   04- sudo passwd root  // set up your root password
   Reboot
```

To Install NodeJS

```
   01- sudo apt-get install git -y
   02- curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -  // replase 12 with latest nodejs (LTS) version
   03- sudo apt-get install nodejs -y
   04- sudo apt-get install gcc g++ make
```

To Install opencv4nodejs

```
01. sudo apt-get install cmake -y
02. sudo npm install -g node-gyp

I am using this steps for raspberry pi os
03. sudo nano /etc/dphys-swapfile
    (Increase the CONF_SWAPSIZE from 100 to 1024)
        sudo /etc/init.d/dphys-swapfile stop
        sudo /etc/init.d/dphys-swapfile start

cd to home dir..
04. mkdir opencv
05. cd opencv
06. sudo npm init -y

07. su  
    // Enter your setup root password

08. sudo npm install --save opencv4nodejs

09. sudo nano /etc/dphys-swapfile
    (Set the CONF_SWAPSIZE back to 100)
```

In index.js and node_modules in same folder

```
const cv = require("opencv4nodejs");
```

In index.js and  node_modules in not in same folder

```
const cv = require("path/opencv/node_modules/opencv4nodejs");
```

! you don't need to install opencv4nodejs for each folders
You can simply call that above way

Hope guys you can understand it...
Any questions feel free to ask...

Thank you