# Receiving npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE after http-proxy-middleware installed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux

[A beginner with Reactjs] 
What I did:

1. Everything worked fine
2. Installed http-proxy-middleware dependency
3. Now I receive the error below even after removing
   http-proxy-middleware
4. Following another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle), also tried: cleaning npm cache, removing package-lock.json, reinstall node-modules (in both server and client folder as I wasn't sure)

error:

```
require(...) is not a function
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Any help resolving this? :)

Answer (score 2):

There were some changes made recently, check out the [latest docs](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware).

The best approach for importing is now:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
```