# npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE (starting issue)

Tags: node.js, npm, startup

thanks for reading this and helping with the issue.

I am trying to run nodejs on Windows machine and start expo client after installing expo-cli. Initially it worked except that live refresh or any other refresh wouldn't work so I tried to delete, uninstall/reinstall nodejj again and now I can't start the thing at all.

I've tried troubleshooting steps from here: [npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle)

but unfortunately they did not help at all...

I don't know if there is a way to perform a fresh install as it may be something that is saved somewhere in cache (even if I delete the directory completely). I'm open to any suggestions here.

Thanks a mil in advance for all your answers and comments.

This is the error from cli:

```
C:\Users\Sergej\NewProject>npm start

> @ start C:\Users\Sergej\NewProject
> expo start

Starting project at C:\Users\Sergej\NewProject
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
error Invalid regular expression: /(.*\\__fixtures__\\.*|node_modules[\\\]react[\\\]dist[\\\].*|website\\node_modules\\.*|heapCapture\\bundle\.js|.*\\__tests__\\.*)$/: Unterminated character class. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sergej\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-31T16_44_26_903Z-debug.log
```

This is the log file text:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.12.0
3 info using node@v12.13.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle @~prestart: @
6 info lifecycle @~start: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Sergej\NewProject\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Sergej\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Sergej\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Sergej\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle @~start: CWD: C:\Users\Sergej\NewProject
10 silly lifecycle @~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'expo start' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: @ start: `expo start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Sergej\NewProject
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.13.0
19 verbose npm  v6.12.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ start: `expo start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, after spending ridiculous amount of time trying to solve the issue (generally all the steps that I've found were involving reinstalling dependencies in one way or another) I've found the answer.

It turns out that the latest node.js issue has some issues with Windows and the only way to fix this for me was to download previous version. I've downloaded it from:

https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

the version that fixed it for me was Node.js 10.x

Quick and painless (almost)

I hope that this will help someone who will be stuck with a similar issue...

Comment: Hi. It still doesn't work for me. I tried with version Node.js 10.x and also deleted node_modules, deleted package-lock.json, npm install and no success. Does anything else come to your mind?, because I am also spending a lot of time and can't figure out...I have also posted the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63670891/eirslettfrontend-maven-plugin1-0npm-npm-start-on-project-exit-status-1-at

Comment: Since then I've installed newest version of Node and it worked, perhaps you can try earlier versions?

Comment: Probably the worst most unhelpful bug I've had to deal with in Nodejs. It was fine on version 10.x, but it appeared consistently on versions 12.x and 14.x. Then suddenly disappeared on version 15.2. I lost 3 days troubleshooting this!

Comment: In my case , 10.x and 8.x not work finally 16.3.0 is ok

Comment: Fingers crossed that mine will work after installing the latest version of node, version 16.13.1, as previously I've had node version 14.4 installed & am getting the same issue.
Very annoying issue indeed!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, i tried these steps in the first place:

```
rm -rf node_modules 

rm -rf package-lock.json

npm install

npm start
```

But nothing worked.

So i digg in the terminal message and found that a `babel-eslint` dependency was pointing to other project directory different from the one i was working on, then i went to that direction and looked for a `node_modules` folder, and voila! that was a problem about running `npm install` where i certainly shouldn't.

A simple `rm -rf node_modules` in my projects container folder was enough to get everything working on again!

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same problem trying to build on gitlab ci, I decided by defining a `CI: false` environment variable and after that it worked, I didn't need to change the node or npm versions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error message. It may be unrelated, but I figured my error. Using VS 2019CE node.js project. For me it was that I typed something like debug("trying to log something to the console") and then I figured it was wrong and added the missing console keywork console.debug("bla") and then runned and it failed ...
the thing is that VS added automatically

```
                      import { debug } from 'webpack';
```

I simply commented it out and it started working again.
I am leaving that here for someone eventually doing the same thing.