# How do I resolve "npm run babel" error in VS code?

Tags: javascript, npm, babeljs, node-modules, npm-scripts

What am trying to do is convert modern javascript code to old code using babel.
When I hit enter on "node_modules/.bin/babel src/index.js -o dizt/azzetz/bundle.js", it works but when I include it in the package.json file then hit enter on "npm run babel" in the terminal it doesn't work.

This is the scripts object inside my "package.json" file.

```
"scripts": {
    "babel": "node_modules/.bin/babel src/index.js -o dizt/azzetz/bundle.js"
  }
```

When I hit enter on "npm run babel" in the terminal, I get this error below.

```
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the 61@1.0.0 babel script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-06T08_05_12_938Z-debug.log
```

This is my .babelrc config file.

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

This is what the log file looks like.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'babel'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v14.15.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebabel', 'babel', 'postbabel' ]
5 info lifecycle 61@1.0.0~prebabel: 61@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle 61@1.0.0~babel: 61@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle 61@1.0.0~babel: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle 61@1.0.0~babel: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\user\Documents\ninja\19. Modern Workflow with Babel & Webpack\61\node_modules\.bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle 61@1.0.0~babel: CWD: C:\Users\user\Documents\ninja\19. Modern Workflow with Babel & Webpack\61
10 silly lifecycle 61@1.0.0~babel: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'babel src/index.js -o dizt/azzetz/bundle.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle 61@1.0.0~babel: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle 61@1.0.0~babel: Failed to exec babel script
13 verbose stack Error: 61@1.0.0 babel: `babel src/index.js -o dizt/azzetz/bundle.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid 61@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\user\Documents\ninja\19. Modern Workflow with Babel & Webpack\61
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "babel"
18 verbose node v14.15.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.8
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error 61@1.0.0 babel: `babel src/index.js -o dizt/azzetz/bundle.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the 61@1.0.0 babel script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Can you please show your .babelrc config file?

Comment: .babelrc config file added!

Comment: Please do post the log file as mentioned by @Camille Louédoc. You need to go here: C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-06T08_05_12_938Z-debug.log

Comment: I've posted the log file.

Comment: try using babel src/index.js -d dizt/azzetz/bundle.js

Comment: I did but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you please tell me the dependencies you installed?

Comment: "@babel/cli": "^7.12.8",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.7"

Comment: what about @babel/polyfill?

Comment: No Sire! I didn't install that one. Let me do it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58648120/npm-err-code-elifecycle-starting-issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744964/what-does-the-elifecycle-node-js-error-mean

Comment: I installed @babel/polyfill but it still did not work. @Megh Agarwal

Comment: Can you show your src/index.js file, please?