# Start a cloned creat-react-app from Github

Tags: reactjs, npm

I cloned a React app to my local computer from github, then when I go to run a npm start, I get this error :

```
> react-tuto@0.1.0 start D:\perso\JS\Projects\react\react-tuto\React-Tuto
> react-scripts start

'react-scripts' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-tuto@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-tuto@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
```

This is my first react-app

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run

```
npm install
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call npm before, since "react-scripts" is not part of your PATH. Do something like:

```
> npm react-scripts start
```

Or this sould also do the trick:

```
> npm run start
```

In case you haven't worked with a package manager before, you need to download the dependencies first. These are listed in the package.json. To install them, run:

```
> npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run something like:

- `npm run start`