# Cannot find module 'tailwindcss'

Tags: vue.js, routes, tailwind-css

I am trying out tailwindcss with my Vue project and while I solved some issue I had with the routing (while trying to break down my code into smaller components), I think I broke something else.

The code was compiling before I added my new routes. I can't seem to find what is wrong in this case.

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/SiteHeader.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/SiteHeader.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'tailwindcss'
```

you can check out this repo, has very few files https://github.com/anaivanm/vue-tw/

Comment: Everything working fine having downloaded your repo and installed the packages. Had to fix the router config though, the `component` part must be a reference not a string. Could be that your `node_modules` is out of sync with the `package-lock`/`yarn.lock` files and you are missing the tailwind dependency?

Comment: I did fix that. Removed the quotes. Restarted the server and I still had that error. I don't really know how to sync node_modules, but I'll just clone the repo again and give it a shot. Thank you!

Answer (score 22):

First :

```
npm run dev
```

Then

```
npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
```

For More Info :
[Tailwind Docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation)

Also check this out :[Restarting NPM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55594993/5134210)

Comment: For those using yarn ```yarn add tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest --dev```