# Call retries were exceeded exception while ng build

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular8, ng-build, angular-cli-v8

I am facing an exception while `ng build` (generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...)

```
An unhandled exception occured: Call retires were exceeded
```

Used versions:

- Angular-CLI: `8.3.20`
- Angular: `8.2.7`
- Node: `12.12.1`

Also in logs, it is mentioned

```
[error] Error: Call retries were exceeded at ChildProcessWorker.initialize
```

Comment: In tsconfig.app.json if you have `target: es2015` change it with `target: es5`

Comment: @MsuArven yes! changing from es2015 to es5 worked for me.

Comment: @Angular Can you please tell, why es2015 was causing this exception?

Comment: This worked for me. I just deleted `node_modules/` and reinstalled.

Comment: its really work just remove node_modules and install again, its working fine

Comment: @TintinSansYeux if we want to use the differential loading we must set the target to es2015

Comment: can anyone shed some light why this works with `es5`?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

#### Update 10.02.2019

This was a problem of the `@angular/cli`. Updating the version to `>= 8.3.22` should fix the issue: [see this comment in #16515](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16515#issuecomment-572625203)

#### ORIGINAL

Basically the build process is running out of memory: see related angular-cli issues [#15493](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/15493), [#16515](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16515)

The recommended remedy is to:

- update node to the latest version e.g. `12.14.0`
- **increase** the **memory** for the build process:

  - in your `package.json` change the `"build"` script to: `node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build`
  - in this case the memory is increased to `4GB`
    depending on the size of your project you may need more

As a quick **workaround** it could also work to use older versions of `angular/cli` and `build-angular`:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.803.20",
    "@angular/cli": "8.3.20",
```

Another workaround is to disable [differential-loading](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#differential-loading) (i.e. skip generation of ES5 bundles), if you want this. Then the build-process will need less memory and may work.

Comment: `node --max_old_space_size=4096` did not worked for me. With 8GB it worked.

Comment: I was facing the same issue and it is fixed with above commad -                                                  
node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build

Comment: only disabling `differential loading` worked for me :(

Comment: It can help if you remove compatibility with older browsers
https://angular.io/guide/deployment#differential-loading

Comment: changed to 2048 on my AWS instance with 2GB RAM – works!

Comment: It has something to do with building the app with "es2015". Using the old target "es5" worked on my side

Answer (score 40):

For me editing tsconfig.json resolved my problem.

> There was a change in @angular-devkit/build-angular which updated the differential loading. To fix this in your Ionic project, change the **target** value from **“es2015” to “es5”** in your tsconfig.json

For more details :- https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-cordova-build-get-stuck-at-generating-es5-bundles-for-differential-loading/180202/4

Comment: But I need es2015, because es5 fails for @angular/fire 6.0.3 and other. 
https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2521

Comment: This is not a "solution", just a hack/patch that will have other negative side effects

Answer (score 9):

Use

```
node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build
```

Comment: This works like I charm. For any other beginner like me out there, you replace your build command in package.json with this.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar issue a few days ago.

I was using Node v10 and could only avoid the exceptions during production build by changing to "target": "es5" in tsconfig.json. This removed differential loading, which was undesireable.

However, after updating to Node v14, I no longer get the exceptions and am able to use "target": "es2015" again.

Comment: This is the current working solution. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The proposed workarounds above did work for me but there is now a much more elegant solution, tested for Angular9 and above.

No need to mess around manually with the JS heap allocation anymore (`node --max_old_space_size=4096`...), which most of us are not comfortable with.

The solution is just to add `"sideEffects": false` to your package.json file.

I found this awesome solution on the official Angular GitHub issues page [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16860#issuecomment-583468795) and it works smoothly for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have also met the same issue, by changing the angular/cli version to 8.3.19, the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This only applicable for those who have migrated their app to angular 10
and increasing memory also not helping

check your "typescript" and "@types/node" in package.json check whether they are compatible or not in https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node

try to downgrade @angular-devkit/build-angular below 0.8XX.X

Answer (score 0):

I literally tried everything for days (multiple!) to fix this issue (without increasing the allowed RAM memory on the server, because I was already on the max allowed (shared hosting)). Nothing worked, except for -

> --loglevel verbose

I was using it to see what was causing problems. But seems that it takes a lot of memory to show the full log in real-time. After removing this from my commands everything builds from the first try.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not using older version of Node.

`nvm use 16` or greater version works for me!

Answer (score -1):

In my case I upgraded the version of node.

I was running v10.* and I upgraded to v12.20.1 and build was completed.

I use Node Version Manager: [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) for switching versions of node.

Answer (score -2):

For react-natives, you can find this helpful.

```
npm  install --save-dev  escape-string-regexp
```