# Why do I get error while using ng bulid command in angular?

Tags: angular-cli

when I run ng build in my angular project I get this error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Call retries were exceeded
```

this is my log:

```
[error] Error: Call retries were exceeded
at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (D:\Angular\TspProjectUi\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\ChildProcessWorker.js:191:21)
at ChildProcessWorker._onExit (D:\Angular\TspProjectUi\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\ChildProcessWorker.js:268:12)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
```

thanks!

Comment: do you get the same error from `ng serve`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59531305/call-retries-were-exceeded-exception-while-ng-build

Comment: no, ng serve work perfectly. and I updated my angular cli