# getting module_not_found error when using webpack?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, html-framework-7

When i used framework7 with webpack, it's showing error with following debug log.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v12.14.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle reminder@1.0.0~prestart: reminder@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle reminder@1.0.0~start: reminder@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle reminder@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle reminder@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\gagan\Projects\hybrid\reminder\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\; C:\Users\gagan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk.\platform-tools; C:\Users\gagan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk.\tools;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\gagan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Users\gagan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\;C:\Users\gagan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\gagan\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle reminder@1.0.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\gagan\Projects\hybrid\reminde
10 silly lifecycle reminder@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run dev'   ]
11 silly lifecycle reminder@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle reminder@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: reminder@1.0.0 start: `npm run dev`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:223:5)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid reminder@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\gagan\Projects\hybrid\reminder
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.14.1
19 verbose npm  v6.13.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error reminder@1.0.0 start: `npm run dev`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the reminder@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Intresting enough i'm even getting the same error while using create-react-app. I aleady reinstalled node, recreate the whole project, runned `npm install` in project root. Don't know why am i getting this error

Comment: You can take a look on the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle answer, could be helpful in `ELIFECYCLE`

Comment: @bsekula i already tried that but still not working