# I'm working on react project.And I got errors like

Tags: reactjs

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! enlite_starter@1.3.1 build: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config internals/webpack/webpack.prod.babel.js --color -p --progress --hide-modules --display-optimization-bailout`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the enlite_starter@1.3.1 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Swetha\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-02-19T06_52_25_635Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

[npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle/49505612#49505612)

Check out my answer to this question. It might help you out.

Answer (score 0):

First run

```
npm run clean
```

Then delete the node_modules folder and run

```
npm install
```

This seems to have solved the problem.

Or if this doesnt work try

Changing access in node_modules directory

```
chmod -R a+rwx ./node_modules
```

idk on what system you are

Comment: clearly on windows given the path