# please provide solution for npm run error in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm trying to run a hello world in react js but shows the following error if i run npm start

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! helloword@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the helloword@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-15T17_12_06_7
00Z-debug.log
```

Comment: this is the log file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle might help