# Node error (webpack-cli) when running npm dev. Can't figure out what the error message means

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, npm, webpack

I'm new to node.

I'm using the Node Express Vue Mongo stack on Windows.
Yesterday my program worked just fine running without any errors, but today when I tried to run NPM dev it crashed.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   '\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'dev'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v13.13.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle client@1.0.0~predev: client@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle client@1.0.0~dev: client@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle client@1.0.0~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle client@1.0.0~dev: DELETED(privacy)
9 verbose lifecycle client@1.0.0~dev: CWD: \Documents\Projecten\soundboard_school\client
10 silly lifecycle client@1.0.0~dev: Args: [
10 silly lifecycle   '/d /s /c',
10 silly lifecycle   'webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js'
10 silly lifecycle ]
11 silly lifecycle client@1.0.0~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle client@1.0.0~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: client@1.0.0 dev: `webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1026:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid client@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd \Documents\Projecten\soundboard_school\client
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
17 verbose argv "\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v13.13.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error client@1.0.0 dev: `webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the client@1.0.0 dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

This is the error message I got, but I can't figure out for the love of me what it means. Googling doesnt give me any answers.
Does anyone have any idea what I could do to fix?
I have tried to clear my cache, delete node_modules and package-lock and use npm-install again multiple times to no avail.

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle

Comment: I had read this. Nothing in there helped, apparently I had the wrong version of webpack-dev-server installed.