# error MSB3073: The command "npm run build" exited with code 1

Tags: .net, angular, gulp

I'm trying to publish my .net application(angular). but I'm getting below error when I try to publish my project.

```
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
5>  npm ERR! errno 1
5>  npm ERR! angular4@1.0.0 build: `gulp build`
5>  npm ERR! Exit status 1
5>  npm ERR! 
5>  npm ERR! Failed at the angular4@1.0.0 build script.
5>  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
5>  
5>  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
5>  npm ERR!     C:\Users\thanujas.BRANDIXLK\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-22T05_10_52_840Z-debug.log
5>C:\Development\.....AllEDI.Web.UI.csproj(651,5): error MSB3073: The command "npm run build" exited with code 1.
6>------ Skipped Publish: Project RockyBrands.AllEDI.Web.UI, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
6>
```

Please advice.

Comment: See if this post helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle

Comment: Do you see any errors that are the output of `gulp build`?