# Starting a react project using npm start

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm trying to learn react.js through this quarantine and I'm having a little bit of trouble. I am using Manjaro Linux with i3WM, it came preloaded with palemoon browser which I only ever used to install firefox developer edition. I recently got around to deleting it and since then whenever I try to use `npm start` npm gives me the following errirs

```
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! user@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the aksh@0.1.0 start script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /home/aksh/.npm/_logs/2020-05-15T19_06_20_971Z-debug.log
```

I'd really appreciate any help I can get,

Thank you for your time

Comment: Please include the full error, debug log or any other useful information

Comment: in doubt try to install again node modules: `npm i`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle)