# Problem with installing react dependencies

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am trying to install react using this command: `npx create-react-app .`

Then I tried to run using this command: `npm run start`

Then I get this error:

```
There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "webpack-dev-server": "3.10.3"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of webpack-dev-server was detected higher up in the tree:

  C:\Users\oa\Desktop\node_modules\webpack-dev-server (version: 3.11.0)

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.
```

As suggested here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle][1] ,
I have tried to fix it using the following commands:

```
delete package-lock.json
npm cache clean --force
npm install
npm start
```

But did not fixed for me.

Just to let you know, my npm version is `6.13.6`, and node version is `v13.8.0`

Comment: I think there is already a node_module in C:\Users\oa\Desktop\ try creating a folder for the app

Comment: Try `npm i -D webpack-dev-server@3.10.3` in your react directory

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I already created  a separate folder for the new app

Comment: thanks @Son Nguyen. I get same error :(

Comment: Switch to C:\Users\oa\Desktop and do the same command. if not work then continue `npm remove webpack-dev-server`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create a `.env` file in the root directory of the project and add this line `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` inside the file.

then try to run `yarn start` or `npm start`.

Comment: Thanks this work for me :) Can you explain to me what was happening

Answer (score 0):

Did you give a project name after `npx create-react-app 'appName'` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple node_modules folders with different versions of dependencies one may conflict with the other -  do the following:

1. Follow steps 1-4 that are initially provided in project directory and commit updated changes locally~

i. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.

ii. Delete node_modules in your project folder.

iii. Remove "webpack" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.

iv. Run `npm install` or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

2. Find the location of the node_modules folder that is not in your project folder ~ this line - (C:\Users\oa\Desktop\node_modules\webpack-dev-server)
3. Go there and delete it
4. once done try `npm start`

should work :)!