# vue cli project won't run - 'babel-code-frame'

Tags: vue.js, babeljs, vue-cli

I am trying to create the absolute basic new vue-cli project, on Linux. The generated project won't run. What am I doing wrong?

I installed the most recent vue cli

```
sudo npm install -g @vue/cli@4.5.0
```

I created a new project:

```
cd /tmp
vue create project1
```

I selected the default presets.

I tried to run the project

```
$ cd project1

$ npm run serve

> project1@0.1.0 serve /tmp/project1
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
 ERROR  Error: Cannot find module 'babel-code-frame'
Error: Cannot find module 'babel-code-frame'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/nodejs/eslint/lib/formatters/codeframe.js:8:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at exports.loadModule (/tmp/project1/node_modules/@vue/cli-shared-utils/lib/module.js:79:14)
    at api.chainWebpack.webpackConfig (/tmp/project1/node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint/index.js:59:26)
    at webpackChainFns.forEach.fn (/tmp/project1/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:236:40)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! project1@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the project1@0.1.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/kevin/.npm/_logs/2020-07-24T17_38_02_618Z-debug.log
```

My npm version is 6.14.7

```
$ npm --version
6.14.7
```

This is package.json after manually hacking in "@babel/code-frame" as suggested by Igor.

```
{
  "name": "project1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/code-frame": "^7.10.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

I tried clearing down npm cache as per this ticket, but it didn't make a difference.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle
```

Comment: install it with `npm install --save-dev @babel/code-frame`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, and it makes no difference. This ends up in the devDependencies, but no build. "@babel/code-frame": "^7.10.4".

Comment: uninstall vue cli with: `sudo npm uninstall -g @vue/cli@4.5.0`, then install again with `npm install -g @vue/cli`. NO SUDO. you should not install npm packages with sudo. then create the project again as usual

Comment: I created a new virtualbox vm using Ubuntu 20.04. I ran the same commands (including with the sudo), and everything worked OK, so my conclusion is that there is something wrong on my PC, rather than wrong with NPM/VUE. I am going to see if I can mark this question as invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I removed and reinstalled nodejs and npm to solve the problem.

```
sudo apt-get remove npm
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
```

Re-install

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
```