# npm build run command gives error at the end

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I also follow the same steps mentioned here: [npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top).
But I am still getting this error. The app run perfectly on `npm start`

I am new to javascript and currently I am working on open source project of **saleor.io**
When I run this command of `npm run build`, I got the below error in output:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! saleor-site@2.10.3 build: `webpack -p`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the saleor-site@2.10.3 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/umair/.npm/_logs/2020-08-06T09_09_26_905Z-debug.l
```

**The output of log is this:**

```
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v12.18.3
19 verbose npm  v6.14.6
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 2
22 error saleor-site@2.10.3 build: `webpack -p`
22 error Exit status 2
23 error Failed at the saleor-site@2.10.3 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 2, true ]
```

Can you please help me out in this where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean this repository https://github.com/mirumee/saleor-storefront ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle)

Comment: Can you share also more logs? From 1 - 17 lines? I see that somebody on this repo had the same issue https://github.com/mirumee/saleor-storefront/issues/839

Comment: I also edit my question and add the link in my question which @Darth has shared and it also not solved my problem

Comment: Please check https://status.npmjs.org/, its an ongoing issue with NPM