# Can't figue out my Deploying issue (MERN App to Heroku)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, heroku, deployment

This is my prompt lines once I try to push: (There are two backend errors and a client one)

```
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! suripanta@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the suripanta@0.1.0 build script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.tBESZ/_logs/2020-08-09T21_38_02_253Z-debug.log
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! backend@1.0.0 build: `cd client && npm run build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the backend@1.0.0 build script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.tBESZ/_logs/2020-08-09T21_38_02_269Z-debug.log
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! backend@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `npm run install-client && npm run build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the backend@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.tBESZ/_logs/2020-08-09T21_38_02_286Z-debug.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
```

And here are my package.json for each one:

client:

```
{
  "name": "suripanta",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
    
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Backed ( server named index.js)

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Backend para las notas de mi sister",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start":"nodemon index.js",   
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build",
    "install-client":"cd client && npm install",
    "heroku-postbuild":"npm run install-client && npm run build"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.18.1",
    "npm": "6.14.5"
  },
  "author": "RichterBelmont DevStudio",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "connect-multiparty": "^2.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.25",
    "validator": "^13.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

Also my index.js from backend:

```
'use strict'

//cargo el mongoose
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
const mongodb_uri_atlas_cluster='mongodb+srv://xxxxx:xxxxx@clusterxxxxx.lw1xj.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority';


mongoose.set('useFindAndModify',false);
mongoose.Promise=global.Promise;
var app=require('./App');
var port=process.env.port || 3900; //primer cambio



//conexión a mongodb


/*
mongoose.connect(mongodb_uri_atlas_cluster || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/suripanta_rest',{useNewUrlParser:true})
        .then(()=>{
            //acá ya me conecté a mongodb
            console.log("conexión a bd se ha realiazo bien! Me voy para arriba");

            //Crear servidor y escuchar peticiones http
            app.listen(3900,()=>{

                console.log('Servidor corriendo correctamente en http://localhost:'+port);

            })


})

*/




mongoose.connect(process.env.mongodb_uri_atlas_cluster || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/suripanta_rest',{useNewUrlParser:true})
        .then(()=>{
            //acá ya me conecté a mongodb
            console.log("conexión a bd se ha realiazo bien! Me voy para arriba");

            if(process.env.NODE_ENV== 'production'){
                app.use(express.static('client/build'));
            }

            //Crear servidor y escuchar peticiones http
            app.listen(3900,()=>{

                console.log('Servidor corriendo correctamente en http://localhost:'+port);

            })


})
```

I think it is a silly detail which I am missing. I am brand new on deploying mern app and I've followed different tutorials since there's not a lot of information on how to for heroku.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Just to confirm, is your project structure something like containing client folder and server folder together under the project root folder?

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle

Comment: Thanks. I revised the post and applied changes.... but nothing happened. Still the same.

Comment: @WenheQi Yes it is!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with one of my project, in which both front-end and back-end are under the same root directory. Here is how my project is organized:

```
myproject
    |----- client
    |        | ---- build
    |        | ---- package.json
    |----- server
    |        | ---- package.json
    |        | ---- index.js
    |----- index.js
    |----- package.json
```

I use the `index.js` under root folder to serve both the front-end(`build` folder) and the server in `server` folder. Beside that, I have three different `package.json` files, one for front-end, one for back-end and one for the overall project.

In order to make it work on Heroku. I have to specify all the build command in `package.json` under root folder, specially the `npm install` command.

Following is my build command as an example:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "build": "cd client && npm install && npm run build && cd ../server && npm install"
  },
```

As Heroku will only execute `npm install` under root folder by default, the client folder and server folder will not have the dependencies installed. In above command I can ask Heroku to execute the commands between `&&` one by one so no dependencies will be missing and it also knows how to serve the app. Your build command might look a little different while the idea is the same.

My repo [here](https://github.com/wenheqi/netcinema) FYR.

Comment: Can you show the details in the index.js file you have in the root folder to understand how you were serving both folders from there

Comment: @ChidimmaNworah all the files are in the repo link of my above answer. The content of the index.js file I have in my root folder is just one line `exports = module.exports = require("./server");`.