# React application npm error code ELIFECYCLE

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, chokidar

Getting below in my react application. I have tried reinstallation of node_module, setting
environment variable C:\Windows\System32

```js
{
  "name": "my_app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "bootstrap-social": "^5.1.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-popper": "^2.2.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "reactstrap": "^8.5.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "description": "This project was bootstrapped with [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.5.4",
    "react": "^16.8.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack": "^4.42.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

this.htmlWebpackPlugin.getHooks is not a function
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my_app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my_app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-08-13T02_51_42_849Z-debug.log

Comment: Did you also delete the `package-lock.json` file before reinstalling or try all of the steps in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49505612/8674094)?

Answer (score 3):

This happens sometimes when there are some files cached.
You can follow the following steps to solve it:

1. Clear the cache. We use the `--force` flag to do it forcefully.

   `$ npm cache clean --force`
2. Delete the node_modules folder and package-lock.json file. You could do that by navigating to the project folder or using the following command:

   `$ rm -rf node_modules && rm package-lock.json`

NOTE: Be very careful using the -rf command in the linux based terminal. Make sure you are in the right directory to use this command.

In Windows: `$ rm -r "node_modules"` in the powershell.

3. Install the node dependecies

   `$ npm install`

This should solve the problem for you. If it still persist, then see what the error in the console says and try to solve that. It might be due to some other reason. :)

Comment: No its not working I have tried that the same error showed again to check console currently its not running at localhost. Please help me with that I am new to programming so it's difficult to solve this problem.

Comment: After the third step could you also try installing this: ```npm i html-webpack-plugin@next```
Aslo CTRL + Shift + F and search for ```new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(env.raw)``` and change it to ```InterpolateHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, env.raw)```

Comment: @sakshimalik did you get a solutions?

Comment: I have other doubt if you help me with that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521612/create-react-native-app-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/63523523#63523523