# 'create-react-native-app' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, yarnpkg

So I want to create a react native application I am getting this error 'create-react-native-app' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file on running create-react-native-app and I also tried react-native, expo but the same error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Create-React-Native-App is not installed on your computer so you can install it by using

```
npm install -g create-react-native-app
```

and then Use

```
create-react-native-app {project_Name}
```

Comment: I have installed the package already the above error shows me on create-react-native-app

Comment: I have installed the above package using yarn can I reinstalled the package again with npm?

Comment: that will result in errors as yarn and npm resolve packages in different ways

Comment: either use npm or yarn, never the two

Answer (score 1):

It seems create-react-native-app is not installed in your system. To install use the following command lines

```
npx create-react-native-app
```

Answer (score 1):

just type `npm install -g react-native` or type `npm install`

Answer (score 1):

if you're using react-native>=63.0 you can try

```
$ npx create-react-native {project_name}
```

or

```
$ npm i -g create-react-native-app
$ create-react-native-app {my-project}
$ cd my-project
$ npm start
```

or just

```
$ npx react-native init {project_name}
```