# How to solve npm err code elifecycle error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-start

I have installed the react js as per the documentation, while going to run the app i am getting error.
The error code are elifecycle npm err errno 1. Can any one kindly help on this error to rectify it. I am also added one more point, i am a new to react js.

[image]

I was also tried some these below steps

Step 1:  npm cache clean

Step 2: removed node modules

Step 3: removed package lock json

Step 4: installed node modules (npm install)

Comment: check this StackOverflow post on NPM err `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/how-to-solve-npm-error-npm-err-code-elifecycle?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top`

Answer (score 0):

i think you are giving command `npm run start` which cause error

just write `npm start app.js` or `npm run app.js`

add name of file which contain server code at `app.js` and if start is your script name there is no error in npm but as you have attached photo there is error in event.js file

Comment: Thanks for the valuable comment, I have run the project as you said above npm start app.js. I am getting same error , can you help me on this..

Comment: at app.js you have to put your main file name as npm run filename

Comment: I have given npm start only, it shows the same error. I have tried what you said above that one also not working.

Comment: than try nodemon it could help

Answer (score 0):

Check if you're running outdated `create-react-app`. If you ejected, then you might want to update `react-scripts`