# Angular build failed wtih

Tags: angular10, ng-build

When I am trying to `ng build` the angular project, it failed generating ES5 bundle. But `ng serve` is working well.

```
Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...
An unhandled exception occurred: Call retries were exceeded
See "C:\Users\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-NswrgZ\angular-errors.log" for further details.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! initial-angular-project@0.0.0 build: `ng build`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the initial-angular-project@0.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-29T10_43_34_845Z-debug.log
```

**angular-errors.log** file message error:

```
[error] Error: Call retries were exceeded
    at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (E:\Work_Cord\InitialAngularProject\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\ChildProcessWorker.js:193:21)
    at ChildProcessWorker._onExit (E:\Work_Cord\InitialAngularProject\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\ChildProcessWorker.js:274:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
```

**angular.json** file

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "InitialAngularProject": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/InitialAngularProject/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "file-saver",
              "rxjs/internal/Observable",
              "js-sha256",
              "devextreme",
              "devextreme-angular"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.common.css",
              "node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.light.css",
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/purple-green.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "10mb",
                  "maximumError": "10mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "InitialAngularProject:build",
            "port": 4201
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "InitialAngularProject:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "InitialAngularProject:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/purple-green.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json",
              "tsconfig.server.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "InitialAngularProject:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "InitialAngularProject:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/InitialAngularProject/server",
            "main": "src/main.server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "outputHashing": "media",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "sourceMap": false,
              "optimization": true
            }
          }
        },
        "app-shell": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:app-shell",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "InitialAngularProject:build",
            "serverTarget": "InitialAngularProject:server",
            "route": "app-shell-path"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "InitialAngularProject:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "InitialAngularProject:server:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "InitialAngularProject",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "05fad134-b906-4d6c-81e2-8fd3f3ad3a2e"
  }
}
```

I have tried a few method but it kept failing. Please refer to the link below.

- https://javascriptforwp.com/forums/topic/npm-err-code-elifecycle-on-terminal/
- https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-boilers.nodejs/issues/7
- [How to solve npm error "npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/how-to-solve-npm-error-npm-err-code-elifecycle)

Comment: I had a similar problem. For me "ngx-charts-heat-map" was the culprit. I had to disable the chart for the build to be successful. I have no explanation as to why the problem was resolved, but just to mention, if it can help you come out of your problem.