# a complete log of this run can be found in npm run dev - ubuntu

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ubuntu, npm, deployment

Good morning, I am trying to make a deployment of a page developed in vue.js and I uploaded all the files and it works, I just need to run "npm run dev" but it throws me the following error. I already ran "npm install" delete package.json and the node_modules folders I ran everything from scratch again but it remains the same

```
> @ dev /var/www/html
> npm run development


> @ development /var/www/html
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

21% building 95/96 modules 1 active .../dist/cjs.js??ref--5-5!/var/www/html/resources/sass/app.scssnpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-01-08T16_00_32_214Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-01-08T16_00_32_256Z-debug.log
```

Comment: The first mentioned error is _"npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE"_ which brings [How to solve npm error “npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/how-to-solve-npm-error-npm-err-code-elifecycle) as the first result in a search (I'm not familiar with npm hence no dupe vote)

Comment: I already do what I suggest in those threads and it remains the same

Comment: There might be something wrong with var/www/html/resources/sass/app.scss . This log output isn't optimized for line-by-line output (because of webpack --progress), could you check if `npm run build` gives a clearer indication of what went wrong?

Comment: Did you delete `package.json` or the `package-lock.json`?
You should check the log files first, like this one `/root/.npm/_logs/2021-01-08T16_00_32_214Z-debug.log`

Answer (score 0):

Try to below way i hope it work

```
1. cmd -> npm cache clean
2. delete package.lock.json file
3. delete node module folder
4. cmd -> npm install
```