# How can I solve strapi's errors?

Tags: node.js, npm, gatsby, strapi

I am trying to develop a portfolio website with **Gatsby** and **Strapi**. Everything was working perfectly fine until I tried flooding **strapi** with some data and while saving it showed "An error occurred", and development server stopped, I tried restarting but showed a lot of errors. I googled the errors and I couldn't solve it. I tried the solution at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/how-to-solve-npm-error-npm-err-code-elifecycle) as well but it was still unsolved. Someone, please help me with this.
After running `npm run develop`, the output was:

```
> portfolio-api@0.1.0 develop C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Dev\gatsby-strapi-portfolio\portfolio-api     
> strapi develop

[2021-01-29T07:16:16.253Z] debug ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
[2021-01-29T07:16:16.256Z] error Error: SQLITE_ERROR: duplicate column name: title
    at Client_SQLite3._query (C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Dev\gatsby-strapi-portfolio\portfolio-api\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\sqlite3\index.js:99:12)
    at Client_SQLite3.query (C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Dev\gatsby-strapi-portfolio\portfolio-api\node_modules\knex\lib\client.js:158:17)
    at Runner.query (C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Dev\gatsby-strapi-portfolio\portfolio-api\node_modules\knex\lib\runner.js:135:36)
    at Runner.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Dev\gatsby-strapi-portfolio\portfolio-api\node_modules\knex\lib\runner.js:228:25)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:461:21)
From previous event:
    at Runner.queryArray (C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Dev\gatsby-strapi-portfolio\portfolio-api\node_modules\knex\lib\runner.js:227:12)
    at C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Dev\gatsby-strapi-portfolio\portfolio-api\node_modules\knex\lib\runner.js:37:25
From previous event:
    at Runner.run (C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Dev\gatsby-strapi-portfolio\portfolio-api\node_modules\knex\lib\runner.js:25:16)
    at SchemaBuilder.Target.then (C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Dev\gatsby-strapi-portfolio\portfolio-api\node_modules\knex\lib\interface.js:14:43)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! portfolio-api@0.1.0 develop: `strapi develop`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the portfolio-api@0.1.0 develop script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-29T07_16_16_353Z-debug.log
```

And the log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'develop'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.10
3 info using node@v14.15.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'predevelop', 'develop', 'postdevelop' ]
5 info lifecycle portfolio-api@0.1.0~predevelop: portfolio-api@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle portfolio-api@0.1.0~develop: portfolio-api@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle portfolio-api@0.1.0~develop: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle portfolio-api@0.1.0~develop: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Dev\gatsby-strapi-portfolio\portfolio-api\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\Amit\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts;C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39;C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\NewPrograms\flutter\bin;C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle portfolio-api@0.1.0~develop: CWD: C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Dev\gatsby-strapi-portfolio\portfolio-api
10 silly lifecycle portfolio-api@0.1.0~develop: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'strapi develop' ]
11 silly lifecycle portfolio-api@0.1.0~develop: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle portfolio-api@0.1.0~develop: Failed to exec develop script
13 verbose stack Error: portfolio-api@0.1.0 develop: `strapi develop`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid portfolio-api@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Dev\gatsby-strapi-portfolio\portfolio-api
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19041
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "develop"
18 verbose node v14.15.4
19 verbose npm  v6.14.10
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error portfolio-api@0.1.0 develop: `strapi develop`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the portfolio-api@0.1.0 develop script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The key output message is:

> error Error: SQLITE_ERROR: duplicate column name: title

According to this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/3490): check all the references in your database, the naming and the changes you may did in the usernames and passwords, also double check your local settings file.

Additionally, you can also delete the offending table (`title`) and remade it again.

On the other hand, on this other [GitHub thread](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/6184) they point to update the `knex` dependency by:

```
npm update knex
```

Answer (score 0):

I got similar problem when creating a new content type.

The problem seems to be the actual database keep old setting
https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/1114

In my case, whole table is duplicated

> [2021-07-08T03:13:19.457Z] debug ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
> [2021-07-08T03:13:19.458Z] error Error: create table `authors` (`id` integer not null primary key autoincrement, `name` varchar(255) null, `published_at` datetime null, `created_by` integer null, `updated_by` integer null, `created_at` datetime null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `updated_at` datetime null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - SQLITE_ERROR: table `authors` already exists

I deleted the model directory `api/author/` . then it's recovered.(but I still can't create author table.)

In your case, it's not about whole table. so editing `api/~~~/models/~~~.settings.json` may solve.