# Node js deploy with C Panel

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, backend

I'm trying to deploy my first project on a server with C Panel, I followed this [guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3Tkpy_lVAA) but when I press "run JS script" I get the following error:

```
returncode: 126
stdout:
> node-mysql@1.0.0 start /home/manteia1/Area_SFTP
> nodemon app.js
stderr:
npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /home/manteia1/nodevenv/Area_SFTP/8/bin/node but npm is using /opt/alt/alt-nodejs8/root/usr/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.
sh: /home/manteia1/Area_SFTP/node_modules/.bin/nodemon: Permission denied
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! node-mysql@1.0.0 start: `nodemon app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-mysql@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/manteia1/.npm/_logs/2021-02-10T14_38_41_625Z-debug.log
```

Comment: npm error ELIFECYCLE.. although i doubt this will help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/how-to-solve-npm-error-npm-err-code-elifecycle JUST IN CASE