# npm start / npm install not working in WSL installer on windows 10 - ERROR EACCES

Tags: reactjs, windows, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to work on some github react apps on my windows 10 computer, but anytime I clone the repo and try to launch it I run into this message :

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TstTB.png)

Here is the debug link that was at the end of the error :

[debug.log](https://filebin.net/ze0ay4iaz8v9w2bo/2021-03-01T21_18_35_547Z-debug.log?t=qk6us6rk)

I looked around a lot for solutions, updated my wsl 1 to wsl 2, updated the ubuntu version my wsl is using, tried running the npm commands as sudo, and I kinda ran out of things to try, and I got to admit I dont understand the error messages I am getting. Sometimes I also get ELIFECYCLE and ENOENT errors.
If anyone that knows what all of that means has any idea how to fix my problem that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Try starting Visual Studio as administrator

Comment: Hi thanks for answering.
I tried this, I get this error message :
https://i.imgur.com/xeiqyvv.png

Comment: Doesn't look like you have run it correctly. Right click on the Visual studio exe and then click run as administrator

Comment: Hello ! Thanks for insisting, I was everytime running it as administrator but once it was opened I did "File - Open folder" and I guess it must launch a new instance of VS Code not as admin.
I just launched as admin, opened the wsl terminal and moved to the correct directory. Still an error, but a different one ! Progress?! Haha thanks again
https://i.imgur.com/HoIZVi6.png

Answer (score 0):

Hello fellow junior developer that had the same problem I had ! It is resolved !
First answer in this post :
[How to solve npm error "npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/how-to-solve-npm-error-npm-err-code-elifecycle)