# Why does npm not start?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

My server works well when I run node app.js. However, I am trying to use nodemon to run my server and it doesn't start.

npm start shows the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 9009
npm ERR! lab11@1.0.0 start: nodemon app.js
npm ERR! Exit status 9009
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the lab11@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "lab11",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

My app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use((request, response, next) => {
    console.log('Middleware!');
    next();
});

app.use((request, response, next) => {
    console.log('Otro middleware!');
    response.send('¡Hola mundo!');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

I already tried to:

- Delete node_modules and run npm install
- Delete package-lock.json, run npm cache clean --force and run npm install
- Delete all files and repeat the installation process
- Add npm to path
- Other solutions to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/how-to-solve-npm-error-npm-err-code-elifecycle)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the content of `app.js` - this error code will sometimes appear when your script has a syntax error. What happens when you simply try to run your script using `node app.js`?

Comment: @esqew thanks for the recommendation. I actualized my question.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/) there are still a few options that you might want to try:

- [Remove the lock file.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45100545/9373031)
  `rm .\package-lock.json`
- [Correct permissions (on *nix)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46019862/9373031)
  `chmod -R a+rwx ./node_modules`
- [Force chache cleaning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49505612/9373031)
  `npm cache clean --force`
- Double-check you're not already running your app in background, locking the port (eg. 8080)