# My react scripts are not running. It says could not find the required file. I tried with whole address in. What to do?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, mern, react-scripts

Could not find a required file.
Name: index.js
Searched in: C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\COLLEGE\WEB_DEVLOPMENT\react-frontend-01-starting-setup\src
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! frontend@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/how-to-solve-npm-error-npm-err-code-elifecycle), could you please share your code and the full log of the error so we can gather more info?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.