# ReactJS npm run build throws elifecycle & export errors (weird)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, build

I'm trying to build a React project via `npm run build` (Creating production build)

- I can use `npm start` just fine and it compiles the react code and works perfectly on the browser

`npm run build - error`
[image: npm run build error]

It's weird since Initially I was only getting the ELIFECYCLE error, then I tried to clear the npm-cache along with deleting the node_modules directory and package-lock.json to reinstall everything fresh.

```
npm cache clean --force
delete node_modules folder
delete package-lock.json file
npm install
```

elifecycle error [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/how-to-solve-npm-error-npm-err-code-elifecycle)

Now that i've done that, the `npm start` command still compiles & runs the react frontend just fine, however when I try to build it, I'm getting this export error aswell, it's weird since this isn't an issue

CheckBoard.js Component:

```js
...
import { checkBoard } from './validation/checker_validation'
//import checker_validation from './validation/checker_validation'
//import { checker_validation } from './validation/checker_validation'
import { tokenChars } from 'ws/lib/validation'
import { parse } from 'uuid'
export default class CheckerBoard extends Component {
    state = {
        gameBoard: this.props.gameData,
        boardInv : this.props.boardInv,
        dispOverlay : {},
        selectedPawn : null,
        selectedValid : []
    }

    //Overlay Initializer:

    //Whenever a pawn is clicked, this function executes:
        //This function executes the validation algorithm, then generates an overlay of all possible moves the user can make

    pawnClick = async (e) => {
        const coord1D = parseInt((e.target.id).split('-')[1]);

        await this.setState({dispOverlay: {'selectedPawn' : coord1D} });

        const newGame = [...(this.state.gameBoard.map((e)=> {return parseInt(e)}))]

        console.log('PAWN CLICK DEBUG:');
        console.log('Game Board:');
        console.log(newGame);
        console.log('Coord 1D');
        console.log(coord1D);

        let valid = this.state.boardInv ? checkBoard(newGame.reverse(),63-coord1D) : checkBoard(newGame, coord1D);

        if(this.state.boardInv){
            valid = [...valid.map((e) => {return e.map( (j) => {return -1*j} )  })];
        }

        this.setState({
            selectedValid : valid
        })

        console.log('Validated: '+JSON.stringify(valid))

        const reducerSum = (pV, cV) => pV + cV;

        for(let v of valid){
            let entry = this.state.dispOverlay;
            
            if(Math.abs(v[0]) < 14){
                entry[parseInt(coord1D)+parseInt(v)] = false; //false is move, true is kill
            } else {

                for(let [i,e] of v.entries()){

                    const killEntry = parseInt(coord1D)+v.slice(0,i+1).reduce(reducerSum,0);
                    entry[killEntry] = true

                }




                //Returns the possible positions of selected Pawn (for every possibility)

                //entry[parseInt(coord1D)+parseInt(v)] = true;
            }
            this.setState({dispOverlay : entry});
        }
    }
...
```

checker_validation.js

```js
const checkBoard = (board, pawnCoord, justKilled) => {
  ...algorithm that returns something...

    if(!foundKill){
        return [[]];
    }

    return res;
}


// console.log(checkBoard(gameboard,42))

module.exports = {
    checkBoard
} 
//exported here
```

I can't figure out why react run build is acting so odd, even after I fully reinitialized npm and the export clearly works on development builds and works, I dont know what the issue is with the build.

Package-lock.json: [Github -> Frontend/package-lock.json](https://github.com/jasonmzx/express_checkers/blob/main/frontend/package-lock.json) (It's very long, that's why I cant copy/paste it onto here)

Comment: try changing `module.exports` to `export { checkBoard }` or simply prefix the `export` keyword before `const checkBoard`

Comment: The problem is most likely related to mixing CommonJS and es6 syntax with create-react-app, that's probably why the build is failing. I saw you're re-using `checkBoard` in your nodejs server. You can use import/export syntax in nodejs by adding `"type": "module"` in your package.json. Although that means you need to refactor all the `require` to `import` and `module.exports` to `export`

Comment: Thanks, after I changed it to the ES6 `export { checkBoard }` as you said, It compiled!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [shidoro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13510672/shidoro) I solved this, I changed the

```js
module.exports = {
    checkBoard
}
```

to the ES6 way:

```js
export{ checkBoard }
```

And it compiled (with warnings, but that's due to some lack of error handling)